# how to connect on premises SQL Server database instance from Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: sql-server, google-compute-engine

I want to connect the SQL Server database(Present in On-Premise) using Google Cloud Compute Engine instance.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can follow the instruction of this [information](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid), because I understand that you want to access data stored by your on-premises SQLServer, over Cloud VPN and think you need to Configure Private Google Access for on-premises [hosts](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid#setting_up_for_on-premises_hosts) and then you  connect as usual to database